# How to pass bean object/value to a jsf(xhtml) page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean, asynchronous

I using Tomcat and PrimeFaces in the current available versions.

I'm facing the problem, that I'm not able to send a value from a managed bean to its xhtml page asynchronously.
This is a code fragment from my xhtml page:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="transcriptionResult" rows="4" cols="120"
                    value="#{transcriptionTabView.currentTranscritpion}" />
```

This is the method which is called asynchronously to re-/set the object/value within the managedbean "transcriptionTabView". Which contains an object called **Transcription  currentTranscription**.

```
@Override
public void trascriptionReady(Transcription t) {
  this.currentTranscription = t;
}
```

I thought this would be enough to reset the view, but nothing happened.

Comment: You need to post more code. Where do you call the method trascriptionReady(Transcription t)? And where do you update the inputTextarea ?

Comment: @EmilKaminski  the `transcriptionReady(Transcription t)` method is called by an asynchronous Event-Handler. I thought if i have getter and setter methods within my bean, each modification on `this.currentTranscription` would trigger an update event on my JSF. But that doesn't work.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for your hint, but is it also possible to call this code `EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
  eventBus.publish("/subscriber", htmlMessage);
  System.out.println("Message Sent at " + new Date());`  for example without pressing a `<p:commandButton ...>` but calling the  code within `transcriptionReady(t)` ?

Comment: @BalusC your hint helped me to solve the problem. thanks :)

Comment: @kami: please create an answer then with what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with the Push functionality of PrimeFaces.
With the hint of BalusC, I read the UserGuide of PrimeFaces Chapter 9. PrimeFaces Push [PDF](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf) and watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfPwEoMyVDc) tutorial. 
These are the steps I have done to solve the problem.

**Step 1:**
I added the following method within my TranscriptionTabView-Bean:

```
public void pushMessage() {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("/resultreceiver", result);
    System.out.println("Message Sent at " + new Date());
}
```

**Step 2.**
I created a Receiver-Bean to receive my pushed messages:

```
 @PushEndpoint(value = "/resultreceiver")
 public class TranscriptionResultReceiver {

    @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
    public String onMessage(String message) {
       return message;
    }
 }
```

**Step 3.**
I added a `<p:inputTextarea>`component to my JSF to display the message:
`<p:inputTextarea rows="6" cols="60" 
            id="transcriptionResult" value="#{transcriptionTabView.result}">
       </p:inputTextarea>`

**Step 4.**
Add a socket to the jsf which waits for the incoming messages:

   `<p:socket channel="/resultreceiver" onMessage="handleMessage"></p:socket>`

Make sure the **channel** is the same as in the Receiver-Bean mentioned **@PushEndpoint** annotation.

**Step 5.**
Add following javascript method to your JSF which is called by the socket tag, when a message is pushed by the TranscriptionTabView-Bean.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function
        handleMessage(data){
            document.getElementById(<GENERATED_ID OF INPUTTEXTAREA>).value=data; 
        }

    </script>
```

As I understood by reading the userguide and watching the youtube video, the method pushMessage in  TranscriptionTabView opens a channel to the JSF and send the message using `eventBus.publish("/resultreceiver", message);` On the client side the socket tag waits for a incoming message on the given channel and if the `onMessage`event occurs, the javascript method `handleMessage` is called to do something with the incoming data.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to this.